# I am getting an error Implicit super constructor SQLiteOpenHelper()

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am very new to android development. I know there are a lot of answers regarding same question but can anyone help me in my code please.
I am getting an error **Implicit super constructor SQLiteOpenHelper() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor**   after creation a class file its code is as below

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String TABLE_COMMENTS = "comments";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_COMMENT = "comment";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "commments.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database creation sql statement
      private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
          + TABLE_COMMENTS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
          + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_COMMENT
          + " text not null);";
```

Comment: post your constructor code..

Comment: Well *why* have you created a subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper` to start with? Do you really need this to be a subclass? Can you use composition instead of inheritance?

Comment: @JonSkeet `SQLiteOpenHelper` is designed to be used by subclassing it. See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)

Comment: @laalto: Ah, I hadn't spotted that it was abstract...

Answer (score 4):

[`SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) has two constructors, taking 4 and 5 arguments. In your derived class constructor, you need to call either of them explicitly, like

```
MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

you must define this in your constructor on first line

```
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
```